# Why does my Raspberry Pi 4 restart my script, and then turn it off?

Tags: python, discord, raspberry-pi, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

I run a Discord py script on my Raspberry Pi 4, but after a while (around 45 minutes) it just restarts when I haven't done anything. After some time it just turns off without an error. Why does this happen? My script worked fine when I used it on heroku.com but now my rasp restarts without me wanting it (I know it restarts because it prints my `on_ready()` message). How can I solve this? I tried running it in the editor on the Raspberry but that also restarts. After some time it also turns off and then my bot doesn't respond anymore. Below is my piece of code for `on_ready`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}'.format(bot))
```

Update:
I think it doesn’t restart it but it runs it again because normally I get 1 embed sent but now like 8 or 7 at once of the same thing

Update 2:
It probably is a connection error, someone in the discord.py discord told me i should handle it in my code. How can i do that?

Comment: I don't believe this is exclusive to raspi, I'm pretty sure it's related to internet connectivity

Comment: Hi @TheFungusAmongUs! I don't think so, if it was the connection i would receive an browser endpoint error right? Should i try it with a LAN cable instead of wifi?

Comment: I'm simply speculating, I've had the same issue when hosting bots on my PC, but never when hosting it on my VPS

Comment: Oh ok, thats weird. But im pretty sure the problem isn't in my file because it runs just fine normally and on heroku so idk.

Comment: It seems like whats happening is that though ur raspi is restarting the actual code is still running the background or something. It's possible that there is some sort of like "timeout" feature for scripts thats default for some time period. I would go over to the discord.py discord and ask there

Comment: Ok thanks i will, do you have a link? I couldn't find it. I asked it on reddit too.

Comment: I have a link: https://discord.gg/dpy (use it to join the server)

Comment: However @maurijn.vd I have to agree with Roopesh, I think there might be a problem on your end, something potentially hardware related? I don't see many of these issues online when searched up. Try some basic troubleshooting steps, like using the included power cable, updating your OS, or downgrading it (if it used to work on an older version of the OS). Also, a few more details would really help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AnonyMous, what kind of details? I will provide them, i use all the original accessoires, and i just updated my raspberry 2 days ago. I will try some troubleshooting tho.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs you were probably right about the connectivity, do you know how i can handle it in my code?

Comment: Huh... did the code work 2 days ago, before you updated your rasbpi?

Comment: @AnonyMous no, sorry, i meant i updated it 2 days ago so my raspberry pi is up-to-date. Do you know how i can handle connection lost in my code?

Comment: Yes I am aware that you meant you updated your rasbpi two days ago, not your code. Did it work back then? To be honest, I don't know much about rasbpi but maybe a firmware update may have caused issues?

Comment: I figured it out, it was really stupid. Discord.py reconnects and they continue the function that was running before the disconnect but i didn't know that so i called the  command again after he reconneted, which resulted in the FUNCTION running multiple times not the whole bot. Thanks tho @AnonyMous :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer wasn't something in my code, Discord.py reconnects and they continue my loop function that was running before the disconnect but i didn't know that so i called the command again after he reconneted, which resulted in the FUNCTION running multiple times not the whole bot, so that was the reason he spammed the embeds. The solution, just ignore the reconnect because everything continues where it disconneted! :)